# Table child rows to be sorted with parent row

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() 
                    { 
                        $("#123").tablesorter(); 
                    } 
                ); 
            $(document).ready(function() 
                    { 
                        $("#123").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
                    } 
                ); 
            </script>
```

This is my script. I want the child rows of my table to be sorted when I sort the parent rows.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the Datatables: https://datatables.net/

Have a look at their sort function: https://datatables.net/reference/api/sort()

Comment: Here is the link to my js file

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/document/-2tygFrAce/jquerytablesorter.html

Comment: I do not want to download your file. For the next time, either include your code in your question or build a fiddle on: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: data table sorts my parent rows but i want the child rows to be sorted with their respective parent rows.

Comment: This may help:https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html